# gzip compression vs ob_gzhandler

Tags: php

In my PHP.INI, `gzip compression` already enabled. May I use `ob_start('ob_gzhandler');` in my PHP pages? And whats different between these two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enabling compression like this:in PHP.ini can be done like this:

```
zlib.output_compression = On
```

this will mean every page PHP serves will be compressed, which may or may not be what you want.

Using ob_start('ob_gzhandler') however will only compress that particular buffer / page and will not affect anything else served by PHP.

Use the second method if you want to compress only certain output. Mixing the two will be pointless, and will probably just use extra CPU cycles trying to compress the already compressed output.

It could be that PHP is clever enough to only do the compression once, but it's still a fruitless exercise to use both approaches together.

It's usually better to enable compression in your web server, although this depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: So, after I disable gzip compression in php.ini I can continue using ob_start('ob_gzhandler'); from Php page.  May I correct?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the two together.

"You cannot use both ob_gzhandler() and zlib.output_compression. Also note that using zlib.output_compression is preferred over ob_gzhandler()."

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php

You can still use ob_start() if you need to buffer your output, you just cannot us the gzhandler callback.

Comment: my PHP.ini `gzip compression` enabled in php.ini, can I enable `zlib.output_compression = Yes` in ini file?

Comment: If I recall gzip compression works with the webserver library mod_gzip in case of apache. What the documentation says is that you cannot explicitly set flags for zlib compression and then use buffer (ob_*) functions because it wouldn't work right.